# Is this possible to do some annotation (like redaction) work on the image using asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have one Image editing work on the asp.net web page.Actually, the work is i have to select the area of the image and then draw some graphical object like black rectangle box on the selected portion of the image to hide the selected part of the image(Just Similar to Redaction Work).Finally have to save the editing work back to the original image.

i have loaded the image on my web page and also allowed the user to draw some rectangle box over the image using javascript function.

I have also written code for saving that image back to the server...but it does not work....

I think the control never crossed this line ( may be some error on this line)

```
var image = document.getElementById("Image2").toDataURL("image/png");
```

for checking purpose, i put one alert statement after the above line...but it is not printed... and nothing happened?...

Java Script code for draw rectangle box over the image :

```
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
        #rubberBand 
        {
            position: absolute;
            visibility: hidden;
            width:0px;
            height:0px;
            border: 2px;border-color:Red;
            background-color:black;
         }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="rubberBand"></div>
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Width="650px" Height="700px"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var IMG;

        function startRubber(evt) {
            if (document.all) {

                var r = document.all.rubberBand;
                r.style.width = 0;
                r.style.height = 0;
                r.style.pixelLeft = event.x;
                r.style.pixelTop = event.y;
                r.style.visibility = 'visible';
                IMG.ondragstart = cancelDragDrop; // otherwise IE will try to drag the image
            }
            else if (document.getElementById) {
                // firefox
                evt.preventDefault();
                var r = document.getElementById('rubberBand');
                r.style.width = 0;
                r.style.height = 0;
                r.style.left = evt.clientX + 'px';
                r.style.top = evt.clientY + 'px';
                r.style.visibility = 'visible';
                r.onmouseup = stopRubber;
            }
            IMG.onmousemove = moveRubber;
        }
        function moveRubber(evt) {
            if (document.all) { // IE
                var r = document.all.rubberBand;
                r.style.width = event.x - r.style.pixelLeft;
                r.style.height = event.y - r.style.pixelTop;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById) { // firefox
                var r = document.getElementById('rubberBand');
                r.style.width = evt.clientX - parseInt(r.style.left);
                r.style.height = evt.clientY - parseInt(r.style.top);
            }
            return false; // otherwise IE won't fire mouseup
        }
        function stopRubber(evt) {
            IMG.onmousemove = null;
        }

        function cancelDragDrop() {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        }
        IMG = document.getElementById('Image2');
        IMG.onmousedown = startRubber;
        IMG.onmouseup = stopRubber;

   </script>
</body>
```

This is my java script code for save Image:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        // Send the canvas image to the server.
        $(function () {
            $("#btnSend").click(function () {
                var image = document.getElementById("Image2").toDataURL("image/png");
                image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Default.aspx/UploadImage',
                    data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert('Image sent!');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Width="650px" Height="700px"/>
<input id="btnSend" type="button" value="Send To Server" />
</body>
```

Back end code for save image:

```
[WebMethod()]
        public static void UploadImage(string imageData)
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\vs-2010projects\\js_save\\js_save\\myimages\\image.png", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);

            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have searched for a ready-made solution, which I don't find strange you didn't find.

You need to break up your problem in small steps that can be solved by you or have been solved by others. In short:

1. Render an image to a webpage
2. Allow the user to 'redact' the image by dragging a box of some sort around the image using JavaScript
3. Upload the box coordinates to your site, where you draw the box on the image and save it as a new image

Alternatively, you can execute step 3 clientside, using a JavaScript canvas, where the browser sends the redacted image back to the server.

You will now have to point out with what of the above points you're having trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance... I am having problem with your step 2 and step 3...

Comment: @Saravanan then it would be helpful to see how far you got. I hope you don't expect me to write the code for you. Update your question and show what you have got.

Comment: am very sorry CodeCaster : I am new to web application and asp.net.right now, i just loaded an image in my asp.net web application and needs to provide the user to draw a rectangle box on the image i loaded...

Comment: @ could you please tell me is this possible with do these things with javascript?

Comment: @Saravanan according to your question history you're new to everything. ;-) You say _"[I] need to provide the user to draw a rectangle box on the image"_ - this has to be done in JavaScript, which I pointed out. Search the web for _"javascript draw rectangle over image"_ you'll have plenty of results. If then your problem is you don't know how to send this to the server, search _"javascript POST variables to ASP.NET"_ (using MVC it'll become a little bit easier, see Web API). If you don't know how to draw images serverside, search that. And so on. Explain every bit you're having trouble with.

Comment: Could you please look at my updated question and suggest me where i am wrong?

Comment: @Saravanan _"...but it does not work...."_ is not an error. Like I said: _"Explain every bit you're having trouble with."_. Show what you are doing and what error exactyl you're getting.